# Potential difference between these points

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws

I do not know how to approach this problem or which theory to apply. Could you please help me to find out the potential difference between the points A and B in the circuit given below.

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is a bit confusing to me. You might simply go back and review the first pages of your literature on circuit analysis. The answer is "5V, obviously! It's given in your circuit!"; I'm not quite sure why you are confused; that's what your battery symbol is supposed to mean.

Comment: The 12V power supply is going to physically destroy the 5V supply. I’m a bit concerned regarding the security of this circuit...

Comment: @Marcus Müller , Since the  5v battery  is connected across point A and B,  it should have a potential difference of 5V, but what I can not believe is that the 12v battery has no effect between points A and B. Could you please point me to the correct direction.

Comment: @rr1303, It is just a hypothetical circuit that draw to understand diode protection clamp.

Comment: @rr1303 You are making assumptions about the voltage sources that are not justified by the question. You have no knowledge about the actual ability of either source to source or sink current.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal voltage source defines the potential between two points. So it is 5V between B and A. There is a voltage drop of 7V across the resistor resulting in a current of 0.875A through all three components.

Comment: Thanks @UweD, How the scenario would change if 5 V cell is replaced by a practical  full wave rectifier type power supply and 12 V cell with output of some stage like opamp or transistor?

Comment: Many rectifiers can deliver only unidirectional output current, so they are not ideal voltage sources, and the behavior will be very different compared to the simple circuit given above. Totally depends on your topology.